# textbox textchange event to click the checkbox in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have a textbox and a datagridview with checkbox. The excel import into datagridview. I add the checkbox into datagridview. I want to input the number into textbox and this number will match the column in datagridview.
please help me!

```
private void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void TextBox2_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
        {
            button4.Focus();
            Button4_Click(sender,e);
            textBox2.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

            if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString() == textBox2.Text)
            {
                row.Cells[0].Value = ((CheckBox)dataGridView1.Controls.Find("DataGridViewCheckBoxCell", true)[0]).Checked;
            }
        }
    }
    private void Form9_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TextBox2_TextChanged);
    }
```

Comment: Is your Column set to accept Checkstate values?

Answer (score 0):

Set this property when setting up your DataGridView

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].ValueType = typeof(CheckState);
```

And then in your Event Handler set the cell using this

```
if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString() == textBox2.Text)
{
    row.Cells[0].Value = CheckState.Checked;
}
```